# Benefit of passing an int by reference vs by value?

Tags: c

1. Is there a performance benefit by passing ints by reference rather than by value ? I say this because if you pass by reference you are creating a 4-byte pointer but if you pass by value you are creating a 4-byte copy of the value anyway. So they both occupy an extra 4-bytes, right ?
2. Is it possible to pass an int literal by reference using a cast: (int *) ? Or do you have to pass a pointer to an int ? See example code below:

   ```
   int func1(int *a){
       (*a)++; // edited from comment by Joachim Pileborg
       printf("%i\n", *a);
       return 0;
   }

   int func2(int a){
       a++;
       printf("%i\n", a);
       return 0;
   }

   int main(void){
       func1(&(int *)5); // an int literal passed by reference using a cast ?
       func2(5);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: The expression `*a++` increases the _pointer_, not what it points to. If you want to increase the value you need to use `(*a)++`.

Comment: I can't believe that even compiles.  You can't take the address of an int literal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The benefit of passing-by-pointer (there are no references in C) is that a function may update the original `int`, i.e. return a value in it. There is no performance benefit; rather, passing-by-pointer may slow your program down because the `int` that is pointed to has to be in addressable memory, so it can't be in a register.

Note that `&(int *)5` does not do what you think it does. `(int *)5` casts the value `5` to a pointer, interpreting it as a memory address. The `&` would give that pointer's address, except that taking the address of a temporary is illegal. You probably meant

```
int i = 5;
func1(&i);
```

Comment: Is it true that passing by pointer creates a 4-byte pointer and passing by value creates a 4-byte copy ? Hence, both methods use an extra 4-bytes in memory ?

Comment: @Jane: Depends on the architecture.  On most 32 bit machines an int is 32 bits and so is a pointer.  On many 64 bit machine/compiler combinations, int is 32 bits but pointers are 64 bits.  So passing a pointer takes 8 bytes but passing an int only takes 4 bytes.